# Using postgresql database files version 8.4 with Docker postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Docker image for postgresql that is 10.4. I have old database files that are postgresql 8.4. I want to upgrade these to use in 10.4 but don't really have a good way to do this. Is it possible to use the Docker image and upgrade the old files?

Comment: You may want to read through the [PostgreSQL documentation on upgrading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at a different document that involved having both installed side by side and it was much more messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can run the `postgres:8.4` image, execute [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) inside it and save the result to the host using, for example, a volume or [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command.

After that you can run `postgres:10` image, provide the result file to it (a volume or `docker cp` again) and [restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) the data.